# retrieving the keys of all variables on an object

Tags: python, class, multiple-inheritance

If I had:

```
class A(object):
    varA = 1

inst = A()
```

Then how would I retrieve the keys of all variables on inst? I'd want something like `["varA"]`

So far, I've gotten this:

```
vars(inst.__class__).keys() #returns ['__dict__', '__weakref__', '__module__', 'varA', '__doc__']
```

I'm fine with that, I'd just ignore the double-under vars. My problem is with multiple layers of inheritance like:

```
class A(object):
    varA = 1

class B(A):
    varB = 2

inst = B()
vars(inst.__class__).keys() #returns ['__module__', '__doc__', 'varB']
```

but I want to retrieve both varB and varA. Any idea how I would go about doing this?

I also tried:

```
vars(super(B, inst).__class__).keys()+vars(inst.__class__).keys()
```

But that didn't do what I expected.

If it matters, I'm using Python 2.6.

**Edit: I actually just stumbled across a very easy way to do this:**
`dir(inst)`

Comment: I did not know that. I'll change my example to conform with the standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a python module, called `inspect` for runtime introspection. Maybe [`inspect.getmembers`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) can help you ...

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I wanted. I've used inspect in the past, but I had forgotten what it's capable of.